want to start working in Latex
I have already installed Latex but I don't know how to write the research paper in that, can you please help me to write it there?

Welcome to TeX SE. Have you tried anything? Do you have a template to work with? Have you looked at some tutorial on the internet?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Welcome. // Suggestions: 1) have a look herer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner, 2) click on the tags you used
